# Unable to load a library in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, dll

I have written a very very simple program in Visual C++ 2008 SP1.
It just adds up two numbers.
The DLLTest.cpp is:

```
#include "DllTest.h"

    __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b)
    {
    return( a + b );
}
```

And DllTest.h is:

```
#ifndef _DLL_TEST_H_
#define _DLL_TEST_H_
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) double Add( double, double);
```

I build the DLL using Visual C++ 2008. When I try to load the library using `loadlibrary`, I get the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> loadlibrary at 422 Building DllTest_thunk_pcwin64 failed.  Compiler output is:
>   DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DllTest.h(5) : error
>   C2054: expected '(' to follow 'EXPORTED_FUNCTION'
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DllTest.h(5) : error C2085: 'Add' : not in
>   formal parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(40) : error C2085:
>   'int8' : not in formal parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(41) :
>   error C2085: 'uint8' : not in formal parameter list
>   DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(42) : error C2085: 'int16' : not in formal
>   parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(43) : error C2085: 'uint16' :
>   not in formal parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(44) : error
>   C2085: 'int32' : not in formal parameter list
>   DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(45) : error C2085: 'uint32' : not in formal
>   parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(46) : error C2085: 'int64' :
>   not in formal parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(47) : error
>   C2085: 'uint64' : not in formal parameter list
>   DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(48) : error C2085: 'voidPtr' : not in formal
>   parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(49) : error C2085: 'string' :
>   not in formal parameter list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(51) : error
>   C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'EXPORTED_FUNCTION'
>   DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(51) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before 'type' DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(52) : error C2085:
>   'EXPORTED_FUNCTIONdoubledoubledoubleThunk' : not in formal parameter
>   list DllTest_thunk_pcwin64.c(52) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before '{'

I want just to load a simple program, written in Visual C++, in MATLAB. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What OS (32/64bit) and version of Matlab are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for considering my question.
I found the problem. Actually, there were two problems:
1) The MATLAB is 64 bit but I made 32-bit DLL and I had to change the settings in Visual Studio to make 64-bit DLL.
2) It seems the compiler that MATLAB uses for loading the DLL, has problem with 'extern "C"' command. So, I changed the header like this:

```
#ifndef DllTest_h
#define DllTest_h

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus

extern "C" {

#endif
__declspec(dllexport) double Add( double, double);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif
```

And Finally it worked.